# How do I replace my rear wheel?

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel, diamondback

My rear wheel was stolen this morning and I am unsure about how to go about getting  a new one without wasting too much time and money (I really want to start biking to work again!). My bike is really old and I'm not sure what parts I need to measure to figure out which type of wheel to get.

It's a Diamondback Apex adventure series that looks exactly like this picture. [image: that looks like this]

I'm completely new to bikes and don't know what the parts are called. It looks like the gear part was left over. Can anybody tell me where to start, and what to measure?

Comment: If you know how many speeds then then it is just a 26" mtn wheel for that many speeds.  That sure looks like a 26" and the width on mtn is pretty standard.  Might be easier to just take it to a shop.

Comment: Okay, would I need any other parts?

Comment: The gears will be a cassette or come with the wheel as a freewheel.  Still say bike shop.  The might have one for $100.

Comment: Yeah, bike shop, if you're not terribly worried about the cost.  Or you can shop around for a junker with a good rear wheel (that's 26" and has the same number of speeds).  (Odd of them to steal just the rear wheel.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy to replace your wheel. The wheel is a 26" (this is a standard mountain bike size wheel), and you will also need to match it to the right cassette. from looking at your bike, its likely a 7 or 8 speed cassette. Your local bike shop should be able to tell what size cassette you need based on your rear deraileur, which wasn't stolen. With wheel, tire and cassette you are probably looking at a $100+ repair if you buy it all new. If there is a local bike co-op in your area that can help you with used parts and labor then you can probably do this for $30-50.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up bringing it to my local bike store and it cost $125 for everything, no new chain though. Unfortunately the bike stores in my area are scarce.

Comment: Glad it worked out! feel free to green check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've recently replaced the rear cassette and chain you'll probably need to replace the chain if you buy a new cassette as they 'wear in' together. You might get away with it but you'll soon know if there is a slipping or crunching noise when you put the pressure down when pulling away or climbing.

If you need a new chain you might also need new middle and small front chainrings on the front if they are excessively warn.

Btw nice bike, those Diamond Backs were quite something back in the late 80s early 90s.

Comment: whats with the down vote? You might not like what I'm saying but if you're chain is worn/stretched more than a new cassette can handle then you're on an upgrade path...

Comment: I agree, my chain doesn't seem to be stretched. I went into the bike store to have my wheel replaced and he didn't replace the chain and charged me way more than I expected. Thanks though! I really like it also